# Верстка дизайна сайта

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Подскажите, какая верстка сайта считается более удобной, табличная, блочная или таблично-блочная? уже перепробовала кучу вариантов, никак не могу определиться...

Answer (score 4):

Есть некоторые аспекты:

Блочная верстка подгружается по блочно, то есть отображается в браузере по мере загрузки блоков.

Табличная верстка подгружается целиком. То есть пока весь хмтл код не подгрузиться она не отобразиться.

Comment: В общем, я так поняла, что большинство за div...)))... спасибо.

Comment: я бы сказал 90% дизайнеров-верстальщиков за div)))

Comment: >> Табличная верстка подгружается целиком. 

Пруф? 15 сек назад наблюдал подгрузку таблицы в фф.

Comment: Это если таблица слишком большая,, то она подгружается и показывается. А так мелкие таблицы, пока не загрузятся полностью, причем с картинками, не отобразятся, хотя там зависит от настроек конечно.

Answer (score 1):

То, что выглядит как таблица, надо верстать таблицей. (с)

Еще: верстать надо с упором на минимальное количество хаков и минимальный объем HTML+JS+CSS (именно их суммы, а не чего-то одного).

ЗЫ: мой обычный способ: разметка шаблона - таблица, все остальное блоками.

Comment: Значит, чтобы ни кому не было обидно, путь будет таблично-блочная)))... потому как надо уже что-то делать...

Comment: Считаю, что делать разметку шаблона таблицей(если это конечно не реально таблица) - дурной тон. Таблицами нужно верстать только то, что должно выглядеть как таблица, не более. Полагаю, что большинство со мной согласится.

Comment: хедер

меню верхнее

блок слева-возможно блок по центру-блок справа

футер

<hr />
сверстаете три резиновые колонки дивами хотя бы в 3 раза большим кодом, чем я таблицей?)

Comment: Кхм, если чисто макет в html - у меня дивами выходит меньше, чем таблицей. Если накинуть сверху минимальный css(только для дивов) - выходит примерно одинаково. Показать код?

Comment: Не "накинуть сверху ксс", а отталкиваться от их суммы)
Ну и ради прикола - че бы и нет))
<hr />
<pre class="code"><table width="100%" height="100%"><tr><td colspan="3" height="200">хедер</td></tr><tr><td colspan="3" height="40">меню</td></tr><tr><td width="200">левый блок</td><td>центральный резиновый блок</td><td width="200">правый блок</td></tr><tr><td colspan="3" height="100">футер</td></tr></table></pre>

Comment: Я имел ввиду красивый код с переносами, но раз кашей... Вот:  
<div>header</div><div><div class="float-class">left menu</div><div class="float-class">center content</div><div class="float-class">right menu</div><div style="clear: left;"></div><div>footer</div>  
.float-class{float: left;width: 300px;}

Comment: эм. вообще-то у меня расставлена ширина-высота и при любом наполнении сайт уже не поедет. Не нужны `clear: both;`, `float: none;` и так далее и тому подобное. И слово "резиновый" там не просто так написано. Т.е. для полноценной разметки мне только в css надо добавить *`table, td { vertical-align: top; border: none; }`* и все)

Comment: Вообще-то и у меня столбцы все резиновые, тяни - не хочу) Минимально рабочий кусок! Ну добавится у меня еще пару строчек css для придания "красоты" - не более. Все это к чему... Дивами кода больше - это да, но не в три и более раза)

Answer (score 1):

Верстать основные блоки надо div-ами, то есть блочная верстка должна быть в основе. Таблицы надо использовать только там, где без них не обойтись, я использую таблицы только для самих таблиц и для позиционирования изображений. В принципе все это можно опять же верстать блоками. Блочная вертка предпочтительнее, потому что код html получается компактным, правда код CSS при этом может сильно раздуться. Еще говорят, что табличная верстка плохо индексируется поисковыми системами.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы советовал делать больше упор на div'ы, вёрстку таблицами использовать только для некоторых элементов при необходимости.

Comment: ещё один фрилансер, понапихают везде дивов и просят овер 900$

Comment: Я не фрилансер, и никуда ничего не пихаю, и ничего ни у кого не прошу. Что нибудь умное лучше бы сказал.

Answer (score 0):

По сути "лишних" тегов в хтмл нету. Обязательно по экспериментируйте с div'ами  table'ами, поймёте для чего могут пригодиться, найдёте + и - в той или иной ситуации.

Answer (score 0):

Фрилансеры.. футакимибыть.. Пихаете везде свои дивы(это же ново, круто!) больше дивов! больше! (на языке фрилансеров - больше $! больше!)

Всего должно быть в меру. Я не могу представить нормальной верстки одними дивами( или одними лишь таблицами).

Так что, Екатерина, вы выбрали правильную золотую серединку.

Comment: Спасибо вам всем, товарищи мужчины!

Comment: Что за неадекватность? Что тебе такого сделали фрилансеры? Почему тебя так беспокоит сколько они просят за вёрстку? Никто из тех кто ответил не сказал что надо верстать только дивами(или только таблицами)! Люди приводят факты, чем дивы в вёрстке лучше таблиц и основываясь на этих фактах советуют именно их.

Answer (score 0):

"табличная" vs "блочная" - такой же холивар, как и "linux" vs "windows", "opera" vs "firefox" и т.д.

У кого как лучше получается верстать, такая и лучше :)

Answer (score 0):

Не подерёмся.
На самом деле плюсы тут очевидны: табличную проще подогнать под 6го ослика даже, а вот с блочной тут сложнее. Что сказать о блочной вёрстке... А вдруг у вас стили не прогрузятся на сайте. Вы в табличной вёрстке такую кашу увидите, что ужаснётесь, а блочная так и будет блоками.
В качестве "просветляющего" могу посоветовать поискать браузер для слепых и дать ему возможность почитать по-разному свёрстанные сайты.
п.с. Юзать таблицу там где должна быть таблица, ИМХО, верный вариант! Остальное - в блоки!

Answer (score 0):

табличная верстка долго загружается по сравнению с блочной. Большинство сайтов делается в блочной верстке ))) но как правило приходится делать комбинированную верстку с преобладанием блочной ))) И желательно проверять дизайн сайта сразу в нескольких браузерах, чтобы поддержать кроссобраузерность

Answer (score -1):

Блочная верстка более гибкая, но и сложнее в изучении. Но выбирать не приходится так как табличную верстку почти ни кто не использует! *Так что однозначно* **блочная**!!!

Comment: Ваши мнения все учтены, Спасибо за вашу отзывчивость. И давайте жить дружно!Я начинаю чувствовать себя уже виноватой,потому как, еще чуть-чуть и вы "подеретесь"... ))))